# Resolving promise within `setTimeout` appears to resolve 300ms faster than the provided delay time

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, asynchronous, promise

I'm attempting to time the execution of a simple asynchronous function as it executes within a React Native app. I tried to test this by creating a sample function which resolves a promise after a known amount of time.

However, I do not see execution times matching when the promise should return using `setTimeout`.

I wrote a simple benchmark test function in Typescript to run a `functionUnderTest` a given number of times, and record the time elapsed during execution:

```
export const timeExecution = async (functionUnderTest: () => void | Promise<void>,
                                    numberOfExecutions: number) : Promise<number[]> => {
    let executionTimesMilli: number[] = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfExecutions; i++) {
        console.log("EXECUTING CALL NUMBER: ", i);
        const startTimeMilli = Date.now();

        await functionUnderTest();

        const endTimeMilli = Date.now();

        const elaspedTimeMilli = endTimeMilli - startTimeMilli;
        executionTimesMilli.push(elaspedTimeMilli);
    }

    return new Promise<number[]>(resolve => {
        resolve(executionTimesMilli);
    });
};
```

Into this timer function above, I passed a function which resolves a promise after a chosen number of milliseconds:

```
export async function sampleAsynchronousFunction() : Promise<void> {
    return new Promise<void>(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME_MILLI);
    });
}
```

I executed this function in a bare-bones React Native app, and see unexpected results. At delay times (`DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME_MILLI`) between 0 and 10,000 ms, I consistently see execution taking between 315-335 ms less time than the input delay time. At delay times of less than 300 ms, this appears as almost no delay at all. [Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/patBt.png) of expected vs. observed times attached.

Why is this observed execution time consistently faster than the value of `DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME_MILLI`? I understand that `setTimeout` may sometimes run slower than expected, but why would it run so consistently faster?

Comment: It's not really clear what your asking here, unfortunately the graph doesn't seem to help, looks nice, but not sure what it's telling us.  btw. `return new Promise<number[]>(resolve => {  resolve(executionTimesMilli);  });` is the same as `return executionTimesMilli`, that promise constructor isn't doing anything useful.

Comment: replace: `    return new Promise<number[]>(resolve => {
        resolve(executionTimesMilli);
    });` with `return executionTimesMilli`